# Exiting application on MessageBox call in constructor

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to show a dialog (message box) before the actual form, and if user selects no, the application should completly be closed. I am trying to use the code below, but even after clicking on No the form will be shown!

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    if (MessageBox.Show("Contiue or not", "Question", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.None, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1) == DialogResult.No)
        Application.Exit();
}
```

I also tried `this.Clsoe` but then I have an exepction on `Application.Run()`

What is the problem? Any idea what would be the best approach for doing so?

Comment: Make yourself a timer. Start the timer on your message box IF. Make the timer to fire after 1 second, execute Exit. When I do such things, I make myself an extra form which is only responsible to return the message box result. Then I open the desired form. What you try to do is Close it while it is loading.

Comment: Why isn't the message box displayed before the form creation?

Comment: The best approach is to ask the user before opening the form.

Comment: The constructor is called too early, before Application.Run() is called.  So there's nothing to exit yet.  Environment.Exit() always works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show your messagebox in the `OnLoad` event instead of the constructor e.g.:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    if (MessageBox.Show("Contiue or not", "Question", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.None, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1) == DialogResult.No)
    {
        Application.Exit(); // or this.Close();
    }
}
```

`Application.Exit()` doesn't work in the constructor because there isn't any form yet, so, no message pump to stop.
Also `this.Close()` raises an error because it causes the call of `Dispose()` on the form; immediately after `Application.Run` try to show up the form, but it is disposed and it throws an exception.

Answer (score 5):

How about putting it in your `Program.cs` (assuming you want to determine whether to launch the app or not)

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        if (
            MessageBox.Show(
                "Contiue or not", "Question", 
                MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, 
                MessageBoxIcon.None, 
                MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1) == DialogResult.Yes)
            Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
```

Comment: Actually, Application.Exit does nothing because there's no message pump active. This code works simply because it skips Application.Run.

Answer (score 1):

Do that in program.cs, like this :

```
  Application.EnableVisualStyles();
  Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
  if (MessageBox.Show("Contiue or not", "Question", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.None, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1) == DialogResult.Yes)
    Application.Run(new Form1());
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't do things like that in a constructor. You should know whether you want to create an object *before* you create it. If you say you want to show the MessageBox before the actual form, then show it before you call the constructor, like before calling `Application.Run()`.

`Application.Exit()` tries to terminate all message pumps, but they are not started yet, because `Application.Run()` starts them.
Also `Application.Exit()` closes all windows of the application, but there are none yet, because your `Form1` isn't even constructed yet.
You're trying to exit the Application before it even has a chance to start running (`Run` hasn't been called yet).
So calling that method inside the application's only form's constructor doesn't make much sense.